# How to count Unique Website Visitor by Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel-5.7

Recently I'm developing a Restaurant Website Dashboard. They want to track the total unique number of visitors to their website. Now how can I solve this problem...? Can anyone please describe how to count the Visitor Number through Laravel...?

Comment: You need to be able to fingerprint the user / browser (client), after that hash the result and store in database, count unique hashes and there is your count. Do not expect this to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to fetch the user's ip address and then through `ajax` update the database and add one record in the database with that `ip`, then for any other `updates to that table`, you will first check if that particular `ip` already exists in the table and if it does, you wouldn't insert a new row. This could be a problem with people with dynamic url, but this should be an easy and quick implementation and it's not `Laravel specific`, so you could do it on every page load you fetch the ip, send it to your backend, save it and you are done

Comment: Can You please Describe The **Process in Details**...?
Controller...?
View...?
Route...? @Nikola Gavric